# neo4j returns actors not directors on findMovieById

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

So am trying out a couple of things in neo4j with spring-data-neo4j.
Am trying to run the cineasts application - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j-examples/cineasts/src/main/java/org/neo4j/cineasts/domain/Movie.java

The application works fine. I am trying to find a movie by id and that works fine except that it returns the actors for the movie but not directors.
The relationship is exactly the same as specified in the Movie.java

I tried to turn on the DEBUG and I found that the query executed underneath is just 

`MATCH (movie:Movie) WHERE movie.id = "603" return movie.`

Could someone help me understand why the movie that is returned comes back with the actors but not directors?

appreciate your help.

thanks

Comment: Where exactly are directors not returned?

Comment: i have a MovieRepository method called findById(id) which returns a movie. The output of this method gives me the movie details with the actors, but not the directors.

Comment: I think that query only returns the movie node and nothing about people who have relationship with that node. If you have access to the Neo4J browser could you run *MATCH (movie:Movie)--(person:Person:Director) WHERE movie.id = "603" return movie, person* ? You should see 2 person nodes and 1 movie node. At least you can verify the data is there.

Comment: You are right. But I think I now have a hang of how this works. I added an `@Fetch` for the Set<directors> in Movie.java and I now see that the directors are being returned. The reason why movie was always returning with actors was because Role had an `@Fetch` for the actor. Thanks for your clues.